# Table resizes with text, but it should not

Tags: html, html-table

I have this problem (I think it's quite simple, however, I cannot solve it):

I normally never work with tables (except this one time). I usually code with divs, but I have to use tables this time for an email design ( O normally also don't use the `<font>` tags etc :P)

Please take a look at the two links below:

http://www.flo-net.org/test1.html page 1
http://www.flo-net.org/test2.html page 2

The difference between the two pages is, that when you add text to the upper row, the bottom left `<td>` resizes with the text. But I don't want that! That `<td>` should stay put at 20px like page 2.

Can anyone help me? Sorry if I did not explain it too well.

Comment: ^^ Why is this editted after more than 7 years? I mean, I cringe about this post I wrote  in my young innocence as well, but I don't think anyone would care anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the top row is all one piece of the design, set `<td colspan="4">`, assuming you have 4 columns.

Comment: Jup, thats it. Thank you! I was adding colspan to the <table> tag (dumb me)